# scroll multiselect in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a multiselect component in Ext js 3. I have a number of entries in it. Now i want to select an entry and scroll multiselect to make it visible to the user. I am able to select an entry but i cannot scroll multiselect.

I have used dataview component and i do this same function using following:
dataviewObj.container.dom.scrollTop = (42 * index);

but cannot implement this is multiselect.

Can someone please tell me how to achieve this with multiselect????

Thank you a lot for help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to edit the Ext extension code itself.

Ext MultiSelect will do scrolling out of the box. You just need to make sure you have added the CSS that it needs:

```
.ux-mselect{
    overflow:auto;
    background:white;
    position:relative; /* for calculating scroll offsets */
    zoom:1;
    overflow:auto;  
}
```

The full set of CSS rules to include in your document is here:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/ux/css/MultiSelect.css

Comment: Thanks @Chris for replying. Could you please give an example of how to scroll to a particular item or selected item? Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of hacking I think I've found the solution to this.

1. Open the Multiselect.js file in an editor.
2. Goto the `onRender` method of the `Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect` class (object).
3. Find the FieldSet creation block of code (`var fs ...`)
4. Add `autoScroll:true` to the fieldset config options.

I had a multiselect with ~200 items in it and this worked like a charm.

This is a change made to the extension code itself, so if you can't afford to do this you'll have to find a work around -- possibly through multiple extending and polymorphism.

Comment: hi thanks a lot for help. I did the changes as u mentioned but then how to scroll to the selected item or to particular index may be???

Comment: I'm made these changes too, but still my selection is not visible.